# Amazon MTurk: can't delete HIT in state 'Reviewable'

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, mechanicalturk

I am using the script offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198700/how-to-delete-still-available-hits-using-boto3-client/55025845#55025845) to delete deployed HITs from the Amazon Mechanical Turk platform. However, I am getting the following exception by the mturk client:

```
An error occurred (RequestError) when calling the DeleteHIT operation: This HIT is currently in the state 'Reviewable'.  This operation can be called with a status of: Reviewing, Reviewable (1574723552282 s)
```

To me, the error msg itself seems to be wrong. Does anybody have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: I got feedback by Amazon MTurk support on this. So if your HIT is in Reviewable status, that means there may be Assignments that have not yet been approved or rejected. When you retrieve the list of Assignments for the HIT, if any are neither approved nor rejected, the HIT may remain in Reviewable or Reviewing status. You will need to move all Assignments to one status or the other to move the HIT our of Reviewable status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somethng like this maybe, I found this somewhere and it can solve your problem,

```
# if hit is reviewable and has assignments, approve assignments
        if status == 'Reviewable':
            assignments = mturk.list_assignments_for_hit(HITId=hit['HITId'], AssignmentStatuses=['Submitted'])
            if assignments['NumResults'] > 0:
                for assign in assignments['Assignments']:
                    mturk.approve_assignment(AssignmentId=assign['AssignmentId'])

        try:
            mturk.delete_hit(HITId=hit['HITId'])
        except:
            print('Not deleted')
```